# Variable Name limits (10000 bytes) while using plumber and R to send JSON files

Tags: r, json, production-environment, plumber

I'm writing production level code using R, plumber and Docker to create an API. The input to my API is a JSON file and the output is also in JSON format. I run into issues when my input file exceeds a certain space/memory limit. How do I handle such issues?

This is the error that I get:

```
<simpleError in do.call(fi$exec, req$args): variable names are limited to 10000 bytes>
```

What's a way to get around this error? How do I input in chunks so that it fixes the space limit?
Also why is it storing it in as a variable name?

The input to the api works if size of of input JSON file is small enough. (approx 46 KB, maybe even more). But fails for 1.3 MB file

Plumber version = 0.4.6

R version = 3.5.2

```
#' @param req Posts in JSON format
#' @post /model

function(req){
  print("I'm here")
  df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(req$postBody)

  op <- do_something(df)

  return(op)

}
```

Is there a way to work around this? Or potentially fix the issue?

EDIT: I wrote print statement later on to detect where exactly the error lies. Turns out it doesn't reach the first line of the function where i use the fromJSON function. I have edited the function now. If I send a small file everything is executed and the print statement is printed, but for a large file it does not print "I'm here".

Reproducible example:

```
temp <- read.csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2018-01.csv")

input_api_json <- toJSON(temp)

write(input_api_json, file = "input_api_json.json")
```

Then create a createAPI.R file

```
 #' @param req Posts in JSON format
#' @post /model

function(req){
  print("I'm here")
  df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(req$postBody)

  op <- df[1,]

  return(op)

}
```

Then create a runAPI.R file

```
pr <- plumber::plumb("createAPI.R")
pr$run(port=8000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

From the terminal; go to the folder and run

```
curl --data-binary "@input_api_json.json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/model
```

Comment: As you can check using `?name`: Names are limited to 10,000 bytes (and were to 256 bytes in versions of R before 2.13.0).

Comment: What exactly does your json file look like? Do you have a variable name that exceeds 10000 bytes? Is that expected? Is it the `do_something` function that throws the error or the `fromJSON` function?

Comment: @MrFlick - I have edited my question. The problem is it doesn't reach the function itself. I have added a print statement to demonstrate my function. Please check out the edited part of the question.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch - That's not what I am asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For us, this error occurs when we send minimized JSON to Plumber. We can easily send 50 thousand lines if it is pretty printed, but the same payload on 1 line without spacing runs into the described error.

Of course, minimized JSON is the best practice for machine-to-machine communication so this seems to be a framework-level bug[1]. Hey, at least there is a workaround!

[1] https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/463